# Remove elements of an array in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to remove the items of an array that coincide in both using map or filter, for example:

```
rmElements :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

and by passing

```
rmElements [1,2] [1,2,3,4]
```

get [3,4]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is some kind of homework?

Anyway the simplest thing I can think of is taking the union (easy with `++`) and removing any element form the intersection:

```hs
rmElements xs ys = filter (\e -> not (e `elem` xs && e `elem` ys)) (xs ++ ys)
```

this is certainly not the most performant solution but it should work reasonably well (at least for your example) - it's a bit unclear of what to do with duplicates and if you need any order so I keep it with that.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I've got it now in a simpler way for me:

```
rmElements x y = filter(\e -> notElem z x) y
```

Comment: this one does not compile (what is `z`?) - I guess you wanted `\e -> notElem e x)` which is fine for your example - but what about if you flip the argument - what are you expecting `rmElements [1,2,3,4] [1,2]` to be? Your version will yield the empty list